# Hyperlink not accepting Lotus Notes URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, lotus-notes

Hi is there a way SharePoint List can open lotus notes link directly. I tried to use Hyperlink but it doesn't accept the URL.

```
 Notes:///482576540025D968/885CF58A51160D024825830E003740F3/EA27ECE86D95F2BD482577F300187C1D
```

Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure have they sorted it but it has been an issue for a while.

Check this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e4045812-e673-47cd-a8c7-d36ae2df6073/mms-url-hyperlinks-wont-open-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

I think what you can do is to use the text column instead of the Hyperlink and play with the formatting to display it as a link.

**EDIT**
Ok I have tested the json formating and it looks like it will not resolve your issue. I tried simple example baesed on hyperlink example here

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Http/https works ok, but as soon as the protocol changes to the notes:// nothing is displayed. Maybe you will have more luck.