# Link lotus notes database to Sharepoint

Tags: database, links

I'm new to SharePoint. Is it possible to link lotus notes databases to SharePoint?
If so, how is this done? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "Link".  You can put a link to anything in a SharePoint links list, but I have a feeling that you are wanting something else.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: Previously my company used Lotus notes and Lotus notes databases for all our content. We have since switched over to another format but due to having so many databases with-in lotus notes we will not be transitioning from them for some time if at all. We have also started to use SharePoint. I would like to use my SharePoint to be the hub for all the other databases. I want a sharepoint page that users can go to and select the link that will direct them to the existing (lotus notes) database.

Comment: When we use the url directly with-in SharePoint it does not work.

Comment: I have been told internally that all we could do is create a hyperlink with-in a document such as PPT and link that document to sharepoint. This seems odd to me to be the answer.

Comment: I hope this helps.

Comment: @DwayneMalone: What you can try is to create HTML file with link to lotus notes URL and then upload HTML file as a source to content editor webpart.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Notes version 4 or later, you could use a Domino server and make the Notes content available via a web interface, then embed that web page in a SharePoint web part.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that in the past and I haven't found solution to the issue using out of the box functionalities.

You would need to develop your own web part that would handle the notes protocol.

[Hyperlink not accepting Lotus Notes URL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250490/hyperlink-not-accepting-lotus-notes-url)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would you have any tips on how to achieve this "need to develop your own web part that would handle the notes protocol."

Comment: its full hands on development using client side object model. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-development-overview

Comment: here you can find some example web parts https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples which are open sourced. You can try to use the scirpt editor https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor and write your code in javascript. That is probably the easiest way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment above, you were advised to put the link in a document and then it would work. Based on this, I suspect the URL for the Lotus Notes databases exceeds SharePoint's limits on how long a URL can be.

We ran into this with links to specific Tableau reports. What we did was create a list with a multi-line text field. We trained users to provide links by entering descriptive text, then making the text a link from the Insert Tab in the ribbon.